# Symfony2 query builder joins to get objects as a single array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have several entities which doesn't have relations set. Currently I have a query:
 $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

```
    $qb->select('post, user')
        ->from('PostBundle:Post', 'post')
        ->leftJoin('UserBundle:User', 'user', 'WITH', 'post.createdBy = user.id')
        ->groupBy('post');

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The problem is that in this way I get posts and users as different array elements. something like:

```
[
    [
       'id'=> post.id,
       'text' => post.text
    ],
    [
       'id'=> user.id,
       'name' => user.name
    ],
    [
       'id'=> post.id,
       'text' => post.text
    ],
    [
       'id'=> user.id,
       'name' => user.name
    ],
    ...
]
```

If I change the select of the query to something like:

$qb->select('post, user.id')

I get

```
[
    [
       'id'=> post.id,
       'text' => post.text,
       'user.id' => user.id,
    ],
    [
       'id'=> post.id,
       'text' => post.text,
       'user.id' => user.id,
    ],
    ...
]
```

but what I really need is to get whole user object instead of a single field so my result would look something like that:

```
 [
        [
           'id'=> post.id,
           'text' => post.text,
           'user' => [
               'id' => user.id,
               'name' => user.name,
        ],
        [
           'id'=> post.id,
           'text' => post.text,
           'user' => [
               'id' => user.id,
               'name' => user.name,
        ],
        ...
    ]
```

I've tried different grouping options with no success. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I'm afraid that, if you don't have any relationship between entities, you could not rely on doctrine to obtain what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query below, in your Post repository class. Will return PostBundle:Post objects as result. To retrieve user, use $post->getUser();

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
              ->leftJoin('UserBundle:User', 'user', 'WITH', 'post.createdBy = user.id');
              ->groupBy('post');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```