# Why is my result array with a hydrated associated entity shaped differently using query builder vs createQuery?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Doctrine's [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) describes two ways to select a record and its relation, one with using a "fetch join" and one not:

#### Fetch join

Fetch join of the address:

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u, a FROM User u JOIN u.address a WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

When Doctrine hydrates a query with fetch-join it returns the class in the FROM clause on the root level of the result array. In the previous example an array of User instances is returned and the address of each user is fetched and hydrated into the User#address variable. If you access the address Doctrine does not need to lazy load the association with another query.

#### The other way

Retrieve a ForumUser and its single associated entity:

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u, a FROM ForumUser u JOIN u.avatar a');
$users = $query->getResult(); // array of ForumUser objects with the avatar association loaded
echo get_class($users[0]->getAvatar());
```

#### My question

When I use the **query builder** it performs like a fetch join and I receive an array with all users and the associations in its root. Like:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u')
    ->from(User::class, 'u');

$qb->join(Address::class, 'a', Join::WITH, 'u.a = a');

$qb->addSelect('a');

// Returns
$result = [
    'user' => // User
    'address' => // Address
];
```

The User object does also have the Address hydrated, as expected.

However I don't want this, I want it shaped like the second example: an array of just Users, with the Address only accesible via the User object. I *could* simply filter the array to get the desired shape, but I feel like that's a workaround due to my lack of understanding.

Is it possible to use the query builder to get a result array shaped like the second example above? Or do I *have* to filter the result array for that? The confusing part for me is that the actual SQL generated by both is identical!

I come from Laravel and Doctrine is brand new to me, so please forgive my naivety on the subject. If I need to clarify anything, just let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer in the related questions section: [Symfony2 query builder joins to get objects as a single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960865/symfony2-query-builder-joins-to-get-objects-as-a-single-array?rq=1)

Instead of joining with the fully qualified names of the entities you should join with the association. So the query becomes:

```
SELECT hs,s,h
  FROM  \App\SoBundle\Entity\HandsetSubscription hs                    
  JOIN  hs.subscription s with s.id = hs.subscription 
                    AND s.mins  = 150 
                    AND s.mb    = 250 
                    AND s.sms   = 150
  JOIN  hs.handset h with h.id = hs.handset
```